# Android Studio unable to connect to MySQL with Java

Tags: java, mysql

So I connect succesffully with Eclipse but once I copy past my code in Android Studio the server refuses the connection.

public static Connection getConnection(){

```
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://81.00......./MYDB";
        String user = "admin";
        String password = "PSWD";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        System.out.println("Connection to db "+url+" OK");
        return conn;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}

    return null;
}
```

I allowed the internet connection in the mannifest of the app.
I added mysql jdbc connector 8.0.20.
I changed the source and target compatibility to 1.8.

The only message I receive is :
I/System.out: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

The server is accessed remootly, on a host. But as I said it works perfectly fine on Eclipse.
Does anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

definitely do not connect between android studio and mysql. Your application can be decompiled very easily. Instead, it will be safer to write RESTAPI or xmlapi with php and api with expressjs. Never establish a database connection in a mobile application.

Comment: THank you for the feedback, I understand that. But would that have more chance working, saftyness asside?